# Is there any point in inheriting ABC Class in Python if you do not have any abstract methods inside?

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, abc

```
# For simplicity, we are not defining getter and setter functions. The reader can
# assume that all class attributes are private and accessed through their respective
# public getter methods and modified only through their public methods function.


class Account:
  def __init__(self, user_name, password, name, email, phone, shipping_address, status=AccountStatus):
    self.__user_name = user_name
    self.__password = password
    self.__name = name
    self.__email = email
    self.__phone = phone
    self.__shipping_address = shipping_address
    self.__status = status.ACTIVE
    self.__credit_cards = []
    self.__bank_accounts = []

  def add_product(self, product):
    None

  def add_productReview(self, review):
    None

  def reset_password(self):
    None


from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Customer(ABC):
  def __init__(self, cart, order):
    self.__cart = cart
    self.__order = order

  def get_shopping_cart(self):
    return self.__cart

  def add_item_to_cart(self, item):
    None

  def remove_item_from_cart(self, item):
    None


class Guest(Customer):
  def register_account(self):
    None


class Member(Customer):
  def __init__(self, account):
    self.__account = account

  def place_order(self, order):
    None
```

I was doing the this Object Oriented Design for Python course online and came across this.
So if you look at the Customer class, they have inherited ABC but there are no abstract methods inside it.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the only reason we inherit ABC for a parent class is so that we provide structure to the future classes that inherit the parent class right?

So if there are no abstract classes inside, what is the point? Or are they just making it future ready?